# CASE WHEN with specific condition and range condition

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am trying to write a query to return values for a range of accounts and some specific accounts, the code I have written so far is below

```
Select 

Case 
        When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0130' then 'A'
        when right(m.account,9) = '1110.0131' then 'B'
        When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0132' then 'C'
        when right(m.account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'D' 
    ELSE '' END AS [Type], Left(M.Account, 4) as Entity, m.activity
FROM Test 

Where
 T.Accounting_Date between '02/01/2019' and '02/28/19' and (Left(M.Account,4) IN (@Entity) OR '' IN (@Entity)) and 
    (Right(M.Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','1110.0132') or substring(T.account,9,4) Between '3000' and '3999')
```

The problem I have is that how do I put a condition after the where clause to only pull a range of accounts i.e. 3000 - 4000 and also some specific ones as already present in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to define `type` in the `from` clause.  Then you can reference it in both the `select` and `where`:

```
select v.type, left(M.Account, 4) as Entity, m.activity
from Test t cross apply
     (values (case when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0130' then 'A'
                   when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0131' then 'B'
                   when right(m.account, 9) = '1110.0132' then 'C'
                   when right(m.account, 9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'D' 
              end)
     ) v(type)
where T.Accounting_Date between '2019-02-01' and '2019-02-28' and
     (Left(M.Account,4) IN (@Entity) OR '' IN (@Entity)) and 
      v.type is not null;
```

Note that I fixed the date format.

And, `IN (@Entity)` probably does not do what you want.  It is equivalent to `= @Entity`.

Comment: Thanks, I think your code is working as intended, the IN(@entity) is used to passed the entity data to a parameter on the SSRS report.

Comment: @Khan82 . . . Ahh, so that works in SSRS.  It doesn't work in T-SQL.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff not sure if this is the right place to ask but is it also possible to aggregate the values for Type A, B, C, D etc?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by aggregation.  You can `group by type` and get the counts, for instance.  You might want to ask another question.

Comment: I meant to sum the activity by Type i.e. Case when 'True' then Sum as 'A'?, right now i am doing it on Visual Studios but its effecting the report performance.

Comment: I tried grouping by type `Group by type`; but i am getting the following error.  "is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to select columns you need and filter it:

```
 Select TYPE, ENTITY, ACTIVITY from (
        Select
        Case 
                When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0130' then 'A'
                when right(m.account,9) = '1110.0131' then 'B'
                When right(m.account,9) = '1110.0132' then 'C'
                when right(m.account,9) between '3000.0000' and '3999.9999' then 'D' 
            ELSE '' END AS [Type], Left(M.Account, 4) as Entity, m.activity
        FROM Test 

        Where
         T.Accounting_Date between '02/01/2019' and '02/28/19' and (Left(M.Account,4) IN (@Entity) OR '' IN (@Entity)) and 
            (Right(M.Account,9) IN ('1110.0130','1110.0131','1110.0132') or substring(T.account,9,4) Between '3000' and '3999')
 ) t 
where TYPE = 'A'; -- your where clauses...
```

Comment: I tried the solution by Gordon, but i will try yours as well and see if there are any performance difference.